# MongoDB Realm Sync session automatically disconnects after connecting

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, realm

I am trying to connect to my Mongo DB collection as an [app user](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/authentication/email-password/), with [flexible sync](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/node/sync/manage-sync-session/). But the sync connection disconnects automatically after a few seconds it seems. Here's my code.

```js
class Person extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = dummyCollectionSchema;
}
class PersonInfo extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = dummyCollection_infoSchema;
}

async function connect() {
  const app = new Realm.App({ id: "application", timeout: 10000 });
  const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword("usr", "pwd");
  const user = await app.logIn(credentials);

  const config = {
    schema: [Person, PersonInfo],
    sync: {
      user,
      flexible: true,
      initialSubscriptions: {
        update: (subs, realm) => {
          subs.add(realm.objects(Person), { name: "Persons" });
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return await Realm.open(config);
}

async function run() {
  const realm = await connect();

  console.log(`>>> Connected: ${realm.syncSession.isConnected()}`);
  // If I write a document to my collection here, it gets synced to Atlas

  // wait 10 seconds
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));  
  console.log(`>>> Connected: ${realm.syncSession.isConnected()}`);
  // If I write a document  here, it does not appear in Atlas. It appears the next time I run the script though.
}

run().catch(err => console.error(`${err}`));
```

I do not get any errors (neither in the code, nor in the realm logs), but the second `console.log` says `Connected: false`. If I write to the database, it always writes to the local realm. But anything that is written after a few seconds of connection does not get synced (gets synced the next time I run my code). What am I doing wrong here?

---

**TL;DR**

Here's the output with `Realm.setLogLevel("trace")`

```
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 15978: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 17876: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 17876
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 17876: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query count: 'state != 2', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query matches: 1, Duration: 11 us
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'state != 2', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 3 us
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 17876: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 26
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query count: 'state == 2', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query matches: 0, Duration: 2 us
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 26
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query count: 'state == 2', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query matches: 0, Duration: 2 us
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 17876
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 15978: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 15978
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[debug] App: update_hostname: https://eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com | wss://ws.eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com
[debug] App: log_in_with_credentials: app_id: application
[debug] App: version info: platform: Linux  version: 6.2.0-34-generic - sdk: JS - sdk version: 12.2.1 - core version: 13.22.0
[debug] App: request location: https://eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/application/location
[debug] App: update_hostname: https://eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com | wss://ws.eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 26 ref 6040
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 26 ref 6040
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'identity == "651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf"', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 10 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 319 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 26
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 26 -> 26
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 27
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 2456 done in 6453 us ref 7776
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[debug] App: do_authenticated_request: GET https://eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/auth/profile
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex released
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 27 ref 7776
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 27 ref 7776
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 27 ref 7776
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'identity == "651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf"', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 11 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 176 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 27
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 27 -> 27
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 28
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 1552 done in 2655 us ref 3984
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 29 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 28
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 28 -> 28
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 29
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 328 done in 1616 us ref 4144
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 29 ref 4144
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 29 ref 4144
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 29 ref 4144
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 78 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 29
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 29 -> 29
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 30
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 328 done in 2287 us ref 4304
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 30 ref 4304
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 30 ref 4304
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 30 ref 4304
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'identity == "651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf"', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 6 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 75 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 30
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 30 -> 30
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 31
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 328 done in 2950 us ref 4464
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 31 ref 4464
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 31 ref 4464
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 31 ref 4464
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'identity == "651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf"', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 6 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 78 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 31
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 31 -> 31
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 32
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 328 done in 2308 us ref 7752
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[detail] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf/flx_sync_default.realm
[trace] Default event loop: start()
[info] Realm sync client ([realm-core-13.22.0])
[debug] Supported protocol versions: 2-10
[info] Platform: Linux Linux 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64
[debug] Build mode: Release
[debug] Config param: one_connection_per_session = false
[debug] Config param: connect_timeout = 120000 ms
[debug] Config param: connection_linger_time = 30000 ms
[debug] Config param: ping_keepalive_period = 60000 ms
[debug] Config param: pong_keepalive_timeout = 120000 ms
[debug] Config param: fast_reconnect_limit = 60000 ms
[debug] Config param: disable_upload_compaction = false
[debug] Config param: disable_sync_to_disk = false
[debug] Config param: reconnect backoff info: max_delay: 300000 ms, initial_delay: 1000 ms, multiplier: 2
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 10 ref 8920
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: '(state == 3 or state == 6)', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 17 us
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'state == 6', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 0, Duration: 2 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex released
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex released
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex released
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex released
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: writemutex released
[trace] Default event loop: thread running
[trace] Default event loop: service run
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[info] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Binding 'node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf/flx_sync_default.realm' to ''
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Activating
[info] Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = true, client reset = false
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_file_ident = 19, client_file_ident_salt = 5735865225673926823
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: last_version_available  = 10
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: progress_download_server_version = 1
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: progress_download_client_version = 0
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: progress_upload_server_version = 0
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: progress_upload_client_version = 0
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Progress handler called, downloaded = 197, downloadable(total) = 197, uploaded = 0, uploadable = 0, reliable_download_progress = false, snapshot version = 10
[info] Connection[1]: Connecting to 'wss://ws.eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com:443/api/client/v2.0/app/application/realm-sync'
[debug] WebSocket::Websocket()
[detail] Resolving 'ws.eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com:443'
[detail] Connecting to endpoint '35.157.33.91:443' (1/1)
[info] Connected to endpoint '35.157.33.91:443' (from '192.168.50.181:49980')
[debug] WebSocket::initiate_client_handshake()
[trace] HTTP request =
GET /api/client/v2.0/app/application/realm-sync?baas_at=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.tAxuGyDQKqribzBIPS-onNYe0P4AkxXsv_-XRe-SI6Q HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.eu-central-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: P9QrN4Wz7222ZDdbBfevSQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#10, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#9, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#8, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#7, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#6, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#5, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#4, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#3, com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#2
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: RealmSync/13.22.0 (Linux Linux 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64) RealmJS/12.2.1 (v6.2.0-34-generic)


[debug] WebSocket::handle_http_response_received()
[trace] HTTP response = HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
connection: Upgrade
date: Wed, 11 Oct 2023 08:03:37 GMT
sec-websocket-accept: CPffXCtDJh11OV7OggpCkXu4hC4=
sec-websocket-protocol: com.mongodb.realm-query-sync#10
server: mdbws
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
upgrade: websocket
vary: Origin
x-appservices-request-id: 652656daab22e8cc093b1621
x-envoy-decorator-operation: baas-sync.baas-prod.svc.cluster.local:8087/*
x-frame-options: DENY


[detail] Connection[1]: Negotiated protocol version: 10
[info] Connection[1]: Connected to app services with request id: "652656daab22e8cc093b1621"
[debug] Connection[1]: Will emit a ping in 21138 milliseconds
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: BIND(session_ident=1, need_client_file_ident=false, is_subserver=false, json_data="{"sessionReason":0}")
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start frozen 805: 10 ref 8920
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query find all: '(state == 3 or state == 6)', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query found: 1, Duration: 14 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: IDENT(client_file_ident=19, client_file_ident_salt=5735865225673926823, scan_server_version=1, scan_client_version=0, latest_server_version=1, latest_server_version_salt=0, query_version=0, query_size=2, query="{}")
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: MARK(request_ident=2)
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: MARK(request_ident=2)
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query find all: 'version > 0 and (state == 1 or state == 2) and snapshot_version > -1', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query found: 0, Duration: 15 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query find all: 'version > 0 and (state == 1 or state == 2) and snapshot_version > -1', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query found: 0, Duration: 7 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: UPLOAD(progress_client_version=10, progress_server_version=1, locked_server_version=1, num_changesets=0)
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Open file: node-stuff/mongodb-realm/application/server-utility/metadata/sync_metadata.realm
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 32 ref 7752
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 32 ref 7752
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Start read 18977: 32 ref 7752
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query find all: 'identity == "651ebd8f56f6ff579c132fcf"', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Query found: 1, Duration: 7 us
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Acquired write lock in 229 us
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Already on version: 32
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Tr 18977: Promote to write: 32 -> 32
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Initiate commit version: 33
[debug] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: Commit of size 328 done in 7385 us ref 3888
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
[detail] DB: 39400 Thread 140081426462720: DB closed
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: Start frozen 18977: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140081426462720: End transaction 18977
>>> Connected: true
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Start read 805: 10 ref 8920
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query find all: 'version > 0 and (state == 1 or state == 2) and snapshot_version > 9', limit = -1
[debug] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: Query found: 0, Duration: 9 us
[trace] DB: 20669 Thread 140069419611712: End transaction 805
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140069394433600: acquire writemutex
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140069394433600: writemutex acquired
[trace] DB: 39400 Thread 140069394433600: writemutex released
[debug] Waiting for 1 connections to drain
[trace] Default event loop teardown
[trace] Default event loop: stop()
[trace] Default event loop: wait for stop
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Initiating deactivation
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: UNBIND
[debug] Draining connections during sync client shutdown
[debug] Connection[1]: Session[1]: Deactivation completed
[debug] Connection[1]: Force closed idle connection
[debug] Connection[1]: Destroying connection object
[trace] Default event loop: thread exiting
>>> Connected: false
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens is you open the realm and write using the exact process shown in the docs [Open Immediately with Background Sync](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/node/sync/configure-and-open-a-synced-realm/#open-immediately-with-background-sync)

Comment: Great question. Just tried (without `initialSubscriptions` just as in the example) and it says not connected in both my `console.log`s

Comment: Now log into the Realm console and review the logs for your app and check for any errors. That's often very revealing.

Comment: No errors as usual. Logs just say `Sync Connection start` -> `Session start` -> `Session end` -> `Connection end`

Comment: Why are you doing this `, timeout: 10000 }` when connecting to Realm. None of the docs indicate that should be done.

Comment: That was a leftover from my actual configuration which has more options set. [Here it is in the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/node/app-services/connect-to-app-services-backend/#configure-a-timeout-for-the-app-client)

Comment: I see. I just build a quick project based on the code in the docs and we are not experiencing any random 'disconnects' - it fully stays sync'd with the server. Did you try your code without the timeout?

Comment: I already did. It did not change anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to keep the `user` object alive to have the sync connection (or so it seems). Realm disconnects when `user` gets garbage collected. (I did not see this mentioned in the docs anywhere)

The following works

```js
let user = null
async function connect() {
  ...
  user = await app.logIn(credentials);
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However, I am not sure the basis is correct. Realm user objects live for 30 minutes after authenticating. So there should be no reason to keep a user object globally like this - we've never had to. We live is Swift so perhaps that's the difference? If you're finding the behavior is not matching what's shown in the docs. you should file a bug report.

Comment: I am not sure either, but I did this on a wild hunch and it appears to be working. And I can reproduce the problem on multiple realm apps with different clusters with different schemas. This could be language specific as you said.